# object 'dbDriver' not found

Tags: r, jupyter-irkernel

the function dbDriver seems to not be present when I run R from the terminal. But it does work if I run it from RStudio.

At first I thought they could be running different installations of R and indeed `.libPaths()` revealed different paths. But by forcing both to run from the same path I still fail to get dbDriver to work on the terminal.

The error message I get is:

`Error: object 'dbDriver' not  found`

Obs: I have installed IRKernel. I don't know if the problem  came before or after this install, but I know that jupyter-kernels sometimes mess with the installations.

Comment: Not sure about your specific issue but I think you probably need to use dbDriver() whereas you are just typing dbDriver as if it is a variable. If this does not fix it please share some of your code that you think is causing the issue.

Comment: In RStudio, when typing dbDriver without the parenteses a message explaining the function comes up. In the terminal there is an erro. Putting the parenteses in the terminal also does not fix the problem. But the error message changes to function not found rather than object.

Comment: As for surrounding code, this error happens on a fresh start of the interpreter. So no surrounding code.

Comment: Maybe your library isn't loaded correctly, since dbDriver is not a part of base R. What happens if you use DBI::dbDriver() instead?

Comment: @bmrn you were right! thank you :) can you write an answer so that I can mark this question as answered?